# Confused about jsp behaviour while setting value based on id

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

In my jsp on readyfunction  i am setting value for some variables

```
$(document).ready(function() {
........////some code.......
var compCode=$('#companyCode').val();
........////some code.......
$("#countrySectorinMemInfo").val(countrySec);   
........////some code.......
});
```

my controller is returning one value say ABC and i am accessing this value using ,

```
<input type="hidden" value="${ABC}" id="companyCode">
```

suppose , if my jsp has more than two fields having same id as "countrySectorinMemInfo"

then how " $("#countrySectorinMemInfo").val(countrySec);" will work......

can anybody explain me ...???

both vaues will get set or only last value will be set ...?????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple elements with the same ID is [illegal](http://validator.w3.org) in [HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/). The browser behaviour is unspecified. Give them a different ID. If you need a common selector, use `name` or `class` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @BalusC

you should use class names instead of IDs. I think all of the JavaScript libraries have methods to get elements by class name.
The jQuery way:

```
// Get all elements with class 'myclass'
var nodes = $('.myclass');
```

The YUI 2.7.0 Selector way:

```
// Get all elements with class 'myclass'
var nodes = YAHOO.util.Selector.query('.myclass');
```

The YUI 2.7.0 getElementsByClass way:

```
// Get all elements with class 'myclass'
var nodes = YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsByClassName('myclass');
```